# Mailto doesn't work when website launched from iOS home screen

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile-safari

I have a web app with bunch of `mailto` links.

E.g. `href="mailto:?subject=pawel%20here!&amp;body=Check%20out%20this%20new%20service%20called"`.

They work as expected on iPhone 6S iOS 12.2 when the web app is opened directly in Safari.

[image]

Unfortunately they don't work when I create a shortcut to the app on the home screen and launch the app from there.

[image]

Any ideas re wha's happening here?

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.location='mailto:email@site.com'; return false;" >Write an email</a>
```

It seems like if working fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that if I add `target="blank"` it works if is launched from home screen, but it left an annoying blank page.

Answer (score -1):

You must set mail after `mailto:`

 See [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MailLinks/MailLinks.html)

Comment: I don’t know who the target is. The user will provide their email address. Also, this works in regular safari.

Comment: I tried with a target email address and it still doesn't work :(